# Identifying Dynamically created ImageButton click and its properties in Xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have used Xamrin.forms.labs to create Imagebutton in shared code. Number of imagebuttons varies according to the number of elements in the list. My questions are

1. How can I identify which button is clicked? (I need the text of the Imagebutton for identification)
2. I have to change the image to Source_on.png on the first click of the image button and    change back to Source.png on second click. (Just like select and unselect)

How can I acheive it??

The code I have used to create ImageButtons is given below.

```
            StackLayout Holder = new StackLayout {
            HorizontalOptions=LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            VerticalOptions=LayoutOptions.Center,
            Orientation=StackOrientation.Horizontal,
            Spacing=2,
            };

        foreach (var options in list)
        {

                var Icon = new ImageButton () {
                    Source=Source.png,
                    BackgroundColor=Xamarin.Forms.Color.Transparent,
                    HorizontalOptions=LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                    VerticalOptions=LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                    Orientation=Xamarin.Forms.Labs.Enums.ImageOrientation.ImageOnTop,
                    Text=labeltxt,
                };

                Icon.Clicked += OnSelected;

                Holder.Children.Add (Icon );

            }
        }
```

Providing a helpful link or sample code will be really helpful..
Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help a lot if you share the code of your `ImageButton`.

That being said... if your ImageButton has a Command property it would also have a CommandParameter property. If it doesn't have that - make them.

You'd set the CommandParameter property with some ID and then bind the Command to the same code, such as

```
ImageButton icon = null;
icon = new ImageButton{
...
  Command= new Command((tag)=>{
     icon.Source = ImageSource.FromFile("...");// see other .FromXYZ methods too
  },
  CommandParameter="<your tag here>",
}
```

BUT... before you do all of that check out the [Xamarin.Forms.Labs](https://github.com/XForms/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/tree/master/src/Xamarin.Forms.Labs/Xamarin.Forms.Labs/Controls), there's an ImageButton there already and you can add that project from NuGet by searching for "Xamarin Forms Labs" in the package manager

Comment: I have used ImageButton in  Xamarin.Forms.Labs, will try Command property and get back on this.

Comment: How can I change the **Source** property of the **ImageButton** using Command Property??

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Can you help me with this?? Letz say, When I click on the ImageButton I change the **Icon1.png** to **Icon2.png** using command property.. on the second click on the same ImageButton button how can I change it back from **Icon2.png** to **Icon1.png**

Comment: Here's a hint: you can also change the CommandParameter from inside the command handler

Comment: A small clarification. Letz say I have 5 dynamically created button, When I click on a ImageButton I need to change all Imagebutton's Source poperty. Is there a way to Identify set of Views with unique ID.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking there, describe your desired UI behavior. `CommandParameter` is an object, you can set it to point to the button itself but you'll have to do that outside of the `icon = {..}` after constructing the object otherwise you'll get null in there. Then change your command handler code to cast the parameter into `ImageButton`

Comment: My desired UI behavior is, I have Set of Five dynamically created Imagebuttons. When I click a ImageButton it should be highlighted as Active other 4 ImageButtons should be shown as Inactive.